# python django validate user input by decorator or extra function? Whats more pythonic?

Tags: python, django, decorator

Im working on a web application. The user can set some parameters to run some algorithms. So when I extract the parameters in the backend, I want to validate them before starting an algorithm, that could crash after a long execution time. Should I use a decorator around the algorithm function or should I pass the parameters to a function like def validate_parameters(), which raises an error if the parameter are incorrect?

Comment: You normally validate with a *form*.

Comment: yes, but also need to validate in backend, as backend cannot expect a valid  request

Comment: I mean a  Django form: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/ this does not only *render* HTML, but also performs validation (at the backend), and removes boilerplate code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual Python 'ask forgiveness not permission' rule of thumb is an attempt to keep the code clean and understandable.  Examining the flow of the code tells you what the expected path is and it is obvious what the exceptional conditions are. In this case there are both downsides to not checking your inputs and you can hide all the checks together in the function so that the code is clean.  I would say the pythonic thing here would be code like

```py
    if not valididate_parameters(params):
        raise ValidationException(get_validation_error_msg(params))
```

Here your `validate_parameters` function just does the check.  The `get_validation_error_msg` function does the heavy lifting of generating something that you can present to the user.  For example it could check all the parameters where the validate function bails out early on any error.  Note that you will have to define the `ValidationException` as a subclass of Exception and catch it at a higher level.

Aside from this idea for general programming, in Django if your parameters are coming in from a form the user fills out you should validate each field within the form code, as Willem Van Onsem points out in his comment.